# How to add multiple chart js script in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a chart from chart js library. The code of script of bar chart is written in some .js file means its not in html now I want to add that script inside my html when i do it then chart not get prepared then I tried `window.onload=function(){Here is the code snippet of chartjs dataset}`. This working fine one chart prepared but I want it 4 times same chart with different ids then it not work it only print chart in last div

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.myBar = new Chart(document.getElementById("bars1"), {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Bags",
          backgroundColor: "#7e3af2",
          // borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [66, 33, 43, 12, 54, 62, 84, 100],
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="min-w-0 p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
<h4 class="mb-4 font-semibold text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300">
    Bars
</h4>
<canvas id="bars1"></canvas>
<div class="flex justify-center mt-4 space-x-3 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">

</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

same chart i want 4 times if i paste this same div below this div with different id in canavs tag and getelementbyid then it wont work only last div chart get printed

Explained

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct your grammar. As it is written, you question includes run-on sentences that are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this solve your problem? if **not** please provide more details

```js
let ids = ['bars1', 'bars2', 'bars3', 'bars4']

ids.forEach(id => {
  window.myBar = new Chart(document.getElementById(id), {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Bags",
            backgroundColor: "#7e3af2",
            // borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [66, 33, 43, 12, 54, 62, 84, 100],
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        /* to remove the legend */
        plugins: {
         legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
      },
    });
})
```

```html
<canvas id="bars1"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars2"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars3"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars4"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the bar chart i am getting a label of bags with a small color purple i want to remove it that color box and label yah i can remove label name "bags " from code but how that color box

Comment: @GouravJangid i updated the solution check it out,

Answer (score 0):

you can just store the ids of all the canvas elements and loops over that array while adding a chart to the respective element with the id

```html
<canvas id="bars1"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars2"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars3"></canvas>
<canvas id="bars4"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    const ids = ['bars1', 'bars2', 'bars3', 'bars4']
    ids.forEach((id) => {
        window.myBar = new Chart(document.getElementById(id),
                  {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                      datasets: [
                      
                        {
                          label: 'Bags',
                          backgroundColor: '#7e3af2',
                          // borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                          borderWidth: 1,
                          data: [66, 33, 43, 12, 54, 62, 84,100],
                        },
                        
                      ],
                    },
                    options: {
                      responsive: true,
                      legend: {
                        display: false,
                      },
                    },
                  }
                )
              }
    })
                  
</script>
```